# How to set a individual operating system language for virtualDesktop users in citrix?

Tags: active-directory, citrix, xenapp

For example User1 - English language operating system
            User 2 - French language operating system

Whenever these users logged in to their Citrix virtual Desktop session .They should have these language operating systems. for user 1 -English and for user 2 - French.

Answer (score 0):

you cant "setup/select" a MUI without rebooting. If you're thinking of performing change of "display language" it is not good.

You will have to prepare a dedicated pool of different languages or seek approval from end-users if having a language input is sufficient enough for them.

Also as far as I know not all "editions" of windows will let you install MUI. (this, I may be wrong as I am now on win8 home ed and cant be bothered to check win7)